# Unable to Call a method if i mentioned its attribute as HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, http-post, action-filter

I have a signin page which users can use to signin,i defined its method in controller as HttpPost,when i try to access it from browser,it shows no file found,if i remove the HttpPost attribute it hits the controller and return the view.Eventhough it pass the values in the form to controller if i didnt mentioned its type as HttpPost .Here my code of Login/SignIn.cshtml:

```
@model BOL.Player_Access
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn","Login",FormMethod.Post)){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Sign In</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlayerEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PlayerEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlayerEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="SignIn" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my LoginController Code is here

```
[AllowAnonymous] //This filter removes authorize filter for this controller alone and allow anonyomous request
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignIn(Player_Access plyr_obj)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your complete code of view . Missing end curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need code for both GET and POST.

You need a GET action to show the form that will be POST'ed

```
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will show the SignIn view.

Then you need a POST action to take the values from the form and send them to the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(Player_Access plyr_obj)
{
    //do some work to authenticate the user

    return View();
}
```

Comment: ,it works..Thanks.But is this the proper way to accomplish this bro,cant i acheive it in a single function?i saw in a video tutorial,they used a single action method for both posting data and showing the form both in a single action.Any idea about how they acheived it bro,Did MVC Supports this feature in any older versions?

Comment: I'm not aware of any version of MVC that "supports" the single show/post semantics.  In the most trivial of cases that may work, but once you start showing properties on the page that aren't posted back, like select lists, it breaks down.

Comment: also investigate the PRG pattern.  Once you post you should redirect back to a Create Get or Index so that you can't post multiple times in a row by accident.  Here's a good explanation https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/